# Selecting entries from a table by checking condition on another table

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables:

**Table1**

```
ID    ServiceID  

01     21
02     22
03     23
```

**Table2**

```
ID    Value

01    NULL
02    value2
03    NULL
```

I want to select those `ServiceIDs` from `Table1` the IDs of which in `Table2` do not have a `NULL` value. The output will be:

```
ServiceID
22
```

I can code in C#, but not at all good with SQL. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ServiceID FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.Value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: use `WHERE t2.Value IS NOT NULL`

Comment: absolutely correct. A minor oversight on my part. Edited. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ServiceID FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.Value IS NOT NULL
```